# Equivalence between curves and fields via relative normalization?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

It is well-known that the category of finitely-generated fields extensions $K/k$ of transcendence degree 1 is equivalent to the category of normal projective curves over $k$ with nonconstant maps.

The proof in Hartshorne's book is given by considering valuations on $K$ and constructing a scheme from it. On the other hand having $K/k$ with $\text{trdeg}(K/k)=1$ we can take the normalisation of $\mathbb{P}^1_{k}$ in $K$ to get a normal scheme $X$ which is also going to be projective. Is this procedure equivalent to that with valuations?